# To covert hexadecimal format to string

Tags: python, string, hex

I am struggling to save some hexadecimal format alphanumerical codes into string.

Let's say

```
a = 0xbe2c
```

how to convert it into

```
 "0xbe2c"
```

I have a list of such codes. If anyone knows the solution, please help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hex(x)` returns a number in hexadecimal notation:

```py
>> a = 0xbe2c
>> a
48684
>> hex(a)
'0xbe2c'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do a variety of things -

```
>>> a = 0xbe2c
>>> hex(a)
'0xbe2c'
>>> str(a)
'48684'
>>> int(a)
48684
```